# Wordpress default favicon affect all pages within the domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a problem with default wordpress favicon. In my WP installation i already changed default WP favicon. But when I upload custom html file to my server (not linked with this wp installation) it has default WP favicon, and I don't know how to fix that.

So the problem is that wp favicon affect all pages within my domain. Is there any way to change that? Maybe I shoud force this favicon with .htaccess file? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the customiser to choose the new favicon you uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting your own fav icon reference in the `<head>` of your uploaded file?

```html
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```